# Office-js Word.Table: How to set alternative text?

Tags: office-js

I'm building an Office And-in for Word and I need to specify an alternative text to each of my auto-generated tables. The question is how I do that?

I can't find anything in the documentation, but am I missing something or is the option simply missing in the current version of the API?